# Querying another table after login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

This seems like it should be simple, but I've tried it every which way and can't seem to get it to work.

I have this login script which I adapted from an online tutorial. What I'd like to do is have users sign in with a username and password, and if these are correct, have it go after their lab results in another table (same database) and display them. I can get it to sign in, but that's it. Here's the login code:

```php
<?php  //Start the Session
session_start();
 require('connect.php');
//3. If the form is submitted or not.
//3.1 If the form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
//3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//3.1.2 Checking the values are existing in the database or not
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
//3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}else{
//3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message.
echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
}
}
//3.1.4 if the user is logged in Greets the user with message
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "Hi " . $username . "! ";
echo "This is the results of your inquiry.<br><br>";




/*This is where I'm assuming the new query needs to go.
Query a different table named "data"  and pick out information according to 
$username which was put in earlier */




echo "<br><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

}else{
//3.2 When the user visits the page first time, simple login form will be displayed.
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Lab Sign In Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Form for logging in the users -->

  <div class="register-form">
    <?php
        if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
            echo $msg;
        }
     ?>

    <h1>Login</h1>

    <form action="" method="post">
      <p><label>User Name :</label> <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder=
      "username"></p>

      <p><label>Password   :</label> <input id="password" type="password" name="password"
      placeholder="password"></p><a class="btn" href="register.php">Signup</a> <input class=
      "btn register" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
  </div><?php }


   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

A "Join" is what I get when I google it but that doesn't seem right. Could someone help?

Comment: What do you mean by 'after their lab results'. And off topic, in the future encrypt passwords and also look into the mysqli library

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a different query for making it easy:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE user = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'");
```

Then you can process with this.

Please note that you should not use MySQL driver as it is deprecated, use MySQLi(mproved) instead. And you should escape the POSTed values, this is very important!

Comment: Thanks for the mysqli suggestions. I'm still mucking it up though. its going to a test.php page, which doesn't exist because its the html at the bottom. With the old code, the url would stay the same but the page would change to the greeting echo. 

The new one seems to want to go to the test.php page which is what's in the form but is nonexistant since its built in the login.php page. 

I know, I'm probably dense, but do really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your last `else` statement is trying to echo the HTML.
2. You should be using `mysqli` or `PDO` since mysql is deprecated.

   ```
   <?php  //Start the Session
   session_start();
   // require('connect.php');
   // Establish connection with database
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
   // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()){ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }
   //3. If the form is submitted or not.
   //3.1 If the form is submitted
   if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
     //3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     //3.1.2 Checking the values are existing in the database or not
     $query = "SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

     $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
     $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
     //3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
     if ($count == 1){
       $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
         echo "Valid";
     }else{
       //3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message.
       echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
     }
   }

   //3.1.4 if the user is logged in Greets the user with message
   if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
     $username = $_SESSION['username'];
     echo "Hi " . $username . "! ";
     echo "This is the results of your inquiry.<br><br>";
   ```

   echo "Username: $username
   ";
   echo "Session Username:".$_SESSION['username'];

   // This is where I'm assuming the new query needs to go.
   // Query a different table named "data"  and pick out information according to $username which was put in earlier

   echo "

   Logout";

   ```
   }else{
     //3.2 When the user visits the page first time, simple login form will be displayed.
   }
   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
   <head>
     <title>Lab Sign In Page</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   </head>

   <body>
     <!-- Form for logging in the users -->

     <div class="register-form">
       <?php
           if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
               echo $msg;
           }
        ?>

       <h1>Login</h1>

       <form action="test.php" method="post">
         <p><label>User Name :</label> <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder=
         "username"></p>

         <p><label>Password   :</label> <input id="password" type="password" name="password"
         placeholder="password"></p><a class="btn" href="register.php">Signup</a> <input class=
         "btn register" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```